# Why do I get lagspikes from sound?

Tags: java, audio, lag

I'm developing a game in Java, and have made an attempt at coding a simple sound system for it made of two class files: one that handles them, and one for each sound file loaded.

My problem is that every once in a while I get a huge lagspike which means a complete stop for like a second or two, really interrupting gameplay. I'm suspecting Garbage control but I'm not entirely sure. The only thing I know for a fact is that the source of the problem lies in the sounds.

Here's my SoundHandler.java:

(The loading of sounds is unimportant, as far as I know it should be unrelated to the problem)

```
package Classes;

import java.io.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;

public class SoundHandler {

Sound Sounds[] = new Sound[1];

public SoundHandler()
{
    if(!LoadSounds("Sounds.cfg"))
        System.out.print("Failiure upon loading sounds!");
}

public boolean LoadSounds(String FileName)
{
    String line = "";
    String SoundName = "";
    String SoundFile = "";
    String[] token3 = new String[10];
    boolean EndOfFile = false;
    int LineCount = 0;
    BufferedReader characterfile = null;

    try
    {
        characterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GameMain.GameFolder+"Data/"+FileName));
    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileex)
        {
            System.out.println(FileName+": file not found.");
            return false;
        }
    while(!EndOfFile && line != null)
    {
        try
        {
            line = characterfile.readLine();
            if(line != null)
            {
                if(line.indexOf("//") == -1 && !line.equals(""))
                    LineCount++;
            }
        }
            catch(IOException ioexception)
            {
                if(LineCount == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(FileName+": error loading file.");
                    return false;
                }
                EndOfFile = true;
            }
    }
    try { characterfile.close(); } catch(IOException ioexception) { characterfile = null; }

    Sounds = new Sound[LineCount];
    EndOfFile = false;
    LineCount = 0;

    try
    {
        characterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(GameMain.GameFolder+"Data/"+FileName));
    }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileex)
        {
            System.out.println(FileName+": file not found.");
            return false;
        }

    try
    {
        line = characterfile.readLine();
        if(line != null)
            if(line.indexOf("//") == -1 && !line.equals(""))
                LineCount++;
    }
        catch(IOException ioexception) { }

    while(EndOfFile == false && line != null) {
        if(line.indexOf("//") == -1 && !line.equals(""))
        {
            line = line.trim();
            line = line.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
            line = line.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
            line = line.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");
            line = line.replaceAll("\t\t", "\t");

            int Spot = line.indexOf("\t");
            SoundName = line.substring(0,Spot);
            SoundFile = line.substring(Spot+1);
            Sounds[LineCount-1] = new Sound(SoundName,SoundFile);
        }

            try {
                    line = characterfile.readLine();
                    if(line != null)
                        if(line.indexOf("//") == -1 && !line.equals(""))
                            LineCount++;
            } catch(IOException ioexception1) { EndOfFile = true; }
    }
    try { characterfile.close(); } catch(IOException ioexception) { }
    return true;
}

public File GetSoundFile(String Name)
{
    File result = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < Sounds.length; i++)
        if(Sounds[i].Name.equals(Name))
            result = Sounds[i].File;
    return result;
}

public Sound GetSound(String Name)
{
    Sound result = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < Sounds.length; i++)
        if(Sounds[i].Name.equals(Name))
            result = Sounds[i];
    return result;
}

public int GetSoundID(String Name)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Sounds.length; i++)
        if(Sounds[i].Name.equals(Name))
            result = i;
    return result;
}

Double MasterVolume = 0.75;

public float CalcVolume(double Vol)
{
    float result = 0f;
    result = -40.0f + (float)(MasterVolume*Vol*40);
    if(result < -40.0f)
        result = -40.0f;
    if(result > 0.0f)
        result = 0.0f;
    return result;
}

public boolean PlaySound(String SoundName, double Vol)
{
    int ID = GetSoundID(SoundName);

    try
    {
        Clip CurrentClip;
        Sounds[ID].Reset(false);
        CurrentClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(Sounds[ID].info);
        CurrentClip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
            public void update(LineEvent event) {
                if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                    event.getLine().close();
                }
            }
        });
        CurrentClip.open(Sounds[ID].sound);

        FloatControl Volume;
        Volume = (FloatControl) CurrentClip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        Volume.setValue(CalcVolume(Vol));
        CurrentClip.start();
    }
    catch(LineUnavailableException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return true;
}
}
```

Here's my Sound.java:

```
package Classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;

public class Sound {

public String Name = "";
public File File = null;

AudioInputStream sound;
DataLine.Info info;
Clip clip;

public Sound(String iName, String FileName)
{
    Name = iName;
    File = new File(GameMain.GameFolder+"Sound/"+FileName+".wav");
    Reset(true);
}

public void Reset(boolean init)
{
    try
    {
        if(!init)
            sound.close();
        sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File);
        info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
    }
    catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
}
```

I've tried searching around for a general way to implement sounds in a game, most I've encountered didn't feature multiple instances of the same sound file running at once, this is what I have so far. I'm sure there are a few tiny inefficiencies especially in the loading code, but there's got to be some leak I'm missing. Any tips for custom GC usage are also welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the sound buffering/playing running in a separate thread?

Comment: Yes, the game uses swing, in fullscreen with a jpanel as contentpane.
I'm not entirely sure about how sounds work in programming, but as far as I know it is not on a seperate thread. It doesn't seem to lag specifically when a sound plays, but after a while (a minute or so) something seems to add up and released in a lagspike. I will try adding a thread right now to see if it helps.

Comment: I've learned that Clip initiates an individual Thread for each sound played. I've also poked my nose around seperating the sound handler into another thread, but I'm having problems trying to make it communicate with the main thread. I DID seach around for examples but what I want is to order a void function to run in the soundhandler thread from the main thread, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to research concurrent threading on the Java Oracle site... I can get a link. There are ways to sync threads together and they do have examples.

[Oracle Concurrency Documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)! ->> [Object Syncing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)